# Success/Error/Warning messages not displaying on Ajax form submit

Tags: messages

I have a form page where there were originally two separate forms, but I have combined them using javascript to submit the data to a controller action. The first is submitted like any Magento form and the second is submitted via ajax after the first. The problem is even though I have the success message and error message code in the controller, the success message never appears on the page after it reloads.

```
public function editprofileAction(){
        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
            list($data, $errors) = $this->validateprofiledata();
            $fields = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            if(empty($errors)){     
                $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
                $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection();
                $collection->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>$this->_getSession()->getCustomerId()));
                foreach ($collection as  $value) {
                    $data = $value;
                }
                ...

           try{
                if(!empty($errors)){
                    foreach ($errors as $message){$this->_getSession()->addError($message);}
                }else{
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Profile information was successfully saved'));}
                    $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/editProfile');
                return;
            }catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e){
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }catch (Exception $e){
                $this->_getSession()->addException($e,  Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Cannot save the customer.'));
            }
            $this->_redirect('customer/*/*');
        }else{
            foreach ($errors as $message) {Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($message);}
            $_SESSION['new_products_errors'] = $data;
            $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/editProfile');
        }

        if(empty($errors)){
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Profile information was successfully saved');
            $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/editProfile');
         }  
    }
    else{
        $this->loadLayout( array('default','marketplace_account_editaccount'));
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle('Profile Information');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }  
}
```

Comment: is error message showing perfectly?

Comment: Nothing is showing.